# Why angular.lowercase method use 'bitwise-or 32' to convert 'A' to 'a'? why not use '+ 32'?

Tags: javascript

```
    var manualLowercase = function(s) {
      return isString(s)
          ? s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, function(ch) {return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) | 32);})
          : s;
    };
    var manualUppercase = function(s) {
      return isString(s)
          ? s.replace(/[a-z]/g, function(ch) {return String.fromCharCode(ch.charCodeAt(0) & ~32);})
          : s;
    };


    // String#toLowerCase and String#toUpperCase don't produce correct results in browsers with Turkish
    // locale, for this reason we need to detect this case and redefine lowercase/uppercase methods
    // with correct but slower alternatives. See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11387
    if ('i' !== 'I'.toLowerCase()) {
      lowercase = manualLowercase;
      uppercase = manualUppercase;
    }
```

Above is angular code. Why use 'ch.charCodeAt(0) | 32' to  convert 'A' to 'a'? Why not 'ch.charCodeAt(0) + 32'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because 32 happens to be a power of 2, `c | 32` is equivalent to `c + 32` if `c & 32 === 0` (i.e. `c` has a 0 in the 32's position). Bitwise operations are usually slightly faster than addition because computers can compute all the bits at the same time rather than having to chain the carries.